# Exec the unistaller of a second application

Tags: windows, inno-setup, uninstallation

I'm trying to unistall all plugins installed on my application, before unistalling it.
I'm using the code bellow, but I have no results...

```
for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(PluginsID)-1 do
begin
    sUnInstallString := 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' + PluginsID[I];
    Exec(sUnInstallString, '/NORESTART','', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, uResultCode);
end;
```

Is there anything wrong?

**EDITED**

I change the code to find the correct unistall string:

```
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Plugins)-1 do
  begin
    sUnInstPath := 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' + Plugins[I];
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    begin    
        Exec(sUnInstallString, '','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, uResultCode);
    end;
  end;
```

But it doesn't work again.... The `sUnInstallString` is filled with the correct value.

Comment: That's because you're trying to execute registry key. You were probably going to query the uninstall path from that registry key, don't you ?

Comment: I found on a tutorial that I have to do on this way. If this is not the way, how can I proceed uninstall?

Comment: So what returns you that `UninstallString` ? Is there a path to the unistaller executable and parameters ?

Comment: Yes. Is the correct path to the unistaller. But the exec command does nothing!

Comment: Then let it show what's wrong, replace the line with `Exec` to [`this`](http://pastebin.com/KpGaEjjq), system will tell you what happened.

Comment: The error: `The directory name is invalid`

Comment: I just have to add the line `StringChangeEx(sUnInstallString, '"', '', True);` before `Exec`. The value cames from Registry with `"`

Comment: That's what no one could answer here as we were not having the real path you were getting from registry.

Answer (score 0):

I just have to add the line

```
StringChangeEx(sUnInstallString, '"', '', True);
```

before `Exec`. The value cames from Registry with the invalid char `"`

Comment: It's not invalid, it's essential.  You're not supposed to use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Exec call to this:

```
Exec('>', sUnInstallString, ...)
```

(Don't strip quotes before doing this.)